# Fastest way to sort sublists in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, data-analysis

What would be the fastest way to sort sublists elemnts in to dictionary in python? I will give the example how I tackled the problem but I think there should be a better way. It is not a problem for smal lists. But I have a lot of data to sort in that way so I need to have optimized version.

**Input:**

```
my_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

my_dict = {}

my_dict['key 0'] = [item[0] for item in my_data]
my_dict['key 1'] = [item[1] for item in my_data]
my_dict['key 2'] = [item[2] for item in my_data]
my_dict['key 3'] = [item[3] for item in my_data]
my_dict['key 4'] = [item[4] for item in my_data]

enter cod`enter code here`e here
```

And this is what I want to get as output.

**Output**

```
{'key 0': [1, 1, 1],
 'key 1': [2, 2, 2],
 'key 2': [3, 3, 3],
 'key 3': [4, 4, 4],
 'key 4': [5, 5, 5]}
```

Comment: If you need it to be optimized from the runtime performance point of view, it's not going to be much faster anyway, because in any implementation you'll need to touch every element of every list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
keys = ["key 0", "key 1", "key 2", "key 3", "key 4"]

print({k: [row[index] for row in my_data] for index, k in enumerate(keys)})
```

EDIT: Probably, the fastest you can get is by using zip and enumerate and not converting the results to a list nor string formatting the keys:

```
print(dict(enumerate(zip(*my_data))))  
# {0: (1, 1, 1), 1: (2, 2, 2), 2: (3, 3, 3), 3: (4, 4, 4), 4: (5, 5, 5)}
```

If the keys are predefined, just use zip again:

```
print(dict(zip(keys, zip(*my_data))))  
# {'key 0': (1, 1, 1), 'key 1': (2, 2, 2), 'key 2': (3, 3, 3), 'key 3': (4, 4, 4), 'key 4': (5, 5, 5)}
```

Comment: Solution is more compact but it is not faster :(

Comment: @Kozaki how big is your data?

Comment: Curently I have around 200 files with arond 30K rows of data. In the future this will grow even bigher

Answer (score 0):

You can try dictionary comprehension with list comprehension init.

```
my_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
my_dict = {'key {}'.format(i): [v[i] for _ in range(len(my_data))] for i, v in enumerate(my_data)}
print(my_dict)
```

Output

```
{'key 0': [1, 1, 1], 'key 1': [2, 2, 2], 'key 2': [3, 3, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `keys` from @Ronie Martinez

```py
my_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
my_dict = {f'key {i}': [v[i] for v in my_data] for i, _ in enumerate(max(my_data))}
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
my_data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
result = {f'key {i}': list(t) for i, t in enumerate(zip(*my_data))}
```

`zip(*L)` is a common idiom to transpose a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I have assumed that the sub-lists could have variable length. For example, you could potentially have something like - [[1,2,3], [1,2]]. In such case, you should use the solution below.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for list_ in my_data:
    for index, number in enumerate(list_):
        my_dict['key ' + str(index)].append(number)
```

Comment: Sub lists have fixed lenght of 8 items in it. The only variable is the number of sublists which is given by the amount of lines in my file